# $injector:modulerr : authentication in AngularJS applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, service

I am having hard time to pass this error:

> [Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=loginApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.3%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DAuthService%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.3%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DAuthService%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520file%253A%252F%252F%252FC%253A%252FUsers%252FAlireza%252Flog-in%252Fclient%252Fvendor%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520file%253A%252F%252F%252FC%253A%252FUsers%252FAlireza%252Flog-in%252Fclient%252Fvendor%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A66%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520a%2520(file%253A%252F%252F%252FC%253A%252FUsers%252FAlireza%252Flog-in%252Fclient%252Fvendor%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A109)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520file%253A%252F%252F%252FC%253A%252FUsers%252FAlireza%252Flog-in%252Fclient%252Fvendor%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A352%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520file%253A%252F%252F%252FC%253A%252FUsers%252FAlireza%252Flog-in%252Fclient%252Fvendor%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A381%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520m%2520(file%253A%252F%252F%252FC%253A%252FUsers%252FAlireza%252Flog-in%252Fclient%252Fvendor%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A322)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(file%253A%252F%252F%252FC%253A%252FUsers%252FAlireza%252Flog-in%252Fclient%252Fvendor%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A229)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520file%253A%252F%252F%252FC%253A%252FUsers%252FAlireza%252Flog-in%252Fclient%252Fvendor%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A398%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520m%2520(file%253A%252F%252F%252FC%253A%252FUsers%252FAlireza%252Flog-in%252Fclient%252Fvendor%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2FC:%2FUsers%2FAlireza%2Flog-in%2Fclient%2Fvendor%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2FC:%2FUsers%2FAlireza%2Flog-in%2Fclient%2Fvendor%2Fangular.min.js:38:154%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(file:%2F%2F%2FC:%2FUsers%2FAlireza%2Flog-in%2Fclient%2Fvendor%2Fangular.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(file:%2F%2F%2FC:%2FUsers%2FAlireza%2Flog-in%2Fclient%2Fvendor%2Fangular.min.js:37:229)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2FC:%2FUsers%2FAlireza%2Flog-in%2Fclient%2Fvendor%2Fangular.min.js:37:398%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(file:%2F%2F%2FC:%2FUsers%2FAlireza%2Flog-in%2Fclient%2Fvendor%2Fangular.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(file:%2F%2F%2FC:%2FUsers%2FAlireza%2Flog-in%2Fclient%2Fvendor%2Fangular.min.js:37:229)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(file:%2F%2F%2FC:%2FUsers%2FAlireza%2Flog-in%2Fclient%2Fvendor%2Fangular.min.js:40:503)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Ac.d%20(file:%2F%2F%2FC:%2FUsers%2FAlireza%2Flog-in%2Fclient%2Fvendor%2Fangular.min.js:19:339)

when I am trying to make an authentication app with AngularJS. I put the code in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6WITqg5U5BNErujkL78K?p=preview).

Here are my codes:

1- app.js

```
"use strict";
(function() {

var app = angular.module('loginApp', ['AuthService', 'Session']);
app.constant('appSettings', {
    title:'Authentication Application',
    version:'1.0'
});
app.constant('AUTH_EVENTS', {
      loginSuccess: 'auth-login-success',
      loginFailed: 'auth-login-failed',
      logoutSuccess: 'auth-logout-success',
      sessionTimeout: 'auth-session-timeout',
      notAuthenticated: 'auth-not-authenticated',
      notAuthorized: 'auth-not-authorized'
});
app.constant('USER_ROLES', {
      all: '*',
      admin: 'admin',
      editor: 'editor',
      guest: 'guest'
});
app.controller('footerController', function($scope, appSettings){
    $scope.appSettings = appSettings;
});

}());
```

2 - applicationcontroller.js

```
"use strict";
(function() {

var applicationcontroller = function ($scope, USER_ROLES, AuthService) {
      $scope.currentUser = null;
      $scope.userRoles = USER_ROLES;
      $scope.isAuthorized = AuthService.isAuthorized;

      $scope.setCurrentUser = function (user) {
        $scope.currentUser = user;
      };
};

applicationcontroller.$inject = ['$scope', 'USER_ROLES', 'AuthService'];

angular.module('loginApp')
  .controller('applicationcontroller', applicationcontroller);

}());
```

3- logincontroller.js

```
"use strict";
(function() {

var logincontroller = function ($scope, $rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService) {
      $scope.credentials = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
      };
      $scope.login = function(credentials){
        AuthService.login(credentials).then(function(user){
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
            $scope.setCurrentUser(user);
        }, function(error){
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
        });
      };
};

logincontroller.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'AUTH_EVENTS', 'AuthService'];

angular.module('loginApp')
  .controller('logincontroller', logincontroller);

}());
```

4- authservice.js

```
"use strict";
(function(){
   var AuthService = function($http, Session){
    var authService = {};

    authService.login = function (credentials) {
      return $http
        .post('/login', credentials)
        .then(function (res) {
          Session.create(res.data.id, res.data.user.id,
                         res.data.user.role);
          return res.data.user;
        });
    };

    authService.isAuthenticated = function () {
      return !!Session.userId;
    };

    authService.isAuthorized = function (authorizedRoles) {
      if (!angular.isArray(authorizedRoles)) {
        authorizedRoles = [authorizedRoles];
      }
      return (authService.isAuthenticated() &&
        authorizedRoles.indexOf(Session.userRole) !== -1);
    };

    return authService;
};
AuthService.$inject = ['$http', 'Session'];
angular.module('loginApp').factory('AuthService', AuthService);
}());
```

5- session.js

```
"use strict";
(function(){
var Session = function(){
        this.create = function (sessionId, userId, userRole) {
        this.id = sessionId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userRole = userRole;
      };
      this.destroy = function () {
        this.id = null;
        this.userId = null;
        this.userRole = null;
      };
};
angular.module('loginApp').service('Session', Session);
}());
```

6- index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="loginApp" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Authentication</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-controller="applicationcontroller">
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <form name="loginForm" ng-controller="logincontroller" ng-submit="login(credentials)" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" ng-model="credentials.username" class="form-control">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">      
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" ng-model="credentials.password" class="form-control">
    </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

    </form>
    <hr class="color-violet">
    <footer class="text-center" data-ng-controller="footerController"> MADE WITH <i class="fa fa-heart color-violet"></i> BY <span class="color-violet">ALAN SABERI</span>. FIND THIS ON <a href="https://github.com/alireza-saberi/customer-application" target="_bank"><span class="color-violet">GITHUB</span></a><div>Version: {{appSettings.version}}</div></footer>
</div>
</div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
     <script src="vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script arc="js/services/authservice.js"></script>
     <script arc="js/services/session.js"></script>
     <script src="js/app.js"></script>
     <script src="js/controllers/applicationcontroller.js"></script>       
     <script src="js/controllers/logincontroller.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have a typo when referencing your script files

```
<script arc="js/services/authservice.js"></script>
<script arc="js/services/session.js"></script>
```

Should be

```
<script src="js/services/authservice.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/session.js"></script>
```

Second -> Your AuthService and Session are not new modules, they are being registered in the same loginApp module based on your code. So you don't inject them into your loginApp module.

Change

```
var app = angular.module('loginApp', ['AuthService', 'Session']);
```

to this

```
var app = angular.module('loginApp', []);
```

Third -> You are loading your service script files before loading your app.js, remember app.js is where you are first defining your loginApp module that you are using to assign your services, so change your script load order to be this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
         <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
         <script src="app.js"></script>
         <script src="session.js"></script>
         <script src="authservice.js"></script>             
         <script src="applicationcontroller.js"></script>       
         <script src="logincontroller.js"></script>
```

Here's your plnkr that's forked and working : http://plnkr.co/edit/5BEIsVxwt8sKwr4HA8Eq?p=preview

Comment: Where is this coming from $scope.setCurrentUser(user); 
is it coming from the ApplicationController