# Authentication and Authorization in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am following a tutorial from this blog

https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec#.4st6f3te5

for Authentication and Authorization in angualrJS

Also trying to fallow some implementation in Stackoverflow
on this link
[$injector:modulerr : authentication in AngularJS applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357412/injectormodulerr-authentication-in-angularjs-applications)

I keep getting this error
$scope.setCurrentUser is not a function
which is coming from the loginController

Can someone help please?

1. this the AuthService

> pmaster.factory('AuthService', ['$http', 'Session', function ($http,
>   Session) {
>       var authService = {};
>
> ```
> authService.login = function (credentials)
> {
>     return $http.get('/api/userLogin/' + credentials).then(function (data)
>     {  
>       // this is the date coming from the Server          //[{"sessionID":"aendypagaw5ytojlxjcvjgyo","userID":"ljanneh1","Role":"superAdmin"}]
>         Session.create(data.sessionID, data.userID, data.Role);
>         return data
>       });
> };
>
> authService.isAuthenticated = function()
> {
>     return !!Session.userId;
> };
>
> authService.isAuthorized = function (authorizedRoles) {
>     if (!angular.isArray(authorizedRoles)) {
>         authorizedRoles = [authorizedRoles];
>     }
>     return (authService.isAuthenticated() &&
>       authorizedRoles.indexOf(Session.userRole) !== -1);
> };
>
> return authService; }]);
> ```

this is the login control

> pmaster.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$location',
>   '$rootScope', 'AUTH_EVENTS', 'AuthService',
>       function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService)
>       {
>
> ```
>     $rootScope.menuHide = true;
>     $rootScope.sideHide = true;
>
>
>     $scope.Login = function()
>     {
>         $scope.loading = true;
>
>         var credentials =
>         {
>             'username': $scope.username,
>             'password': $scope.password
>
>         }
>
>         var obj = credentials.username + "-" + credentials.password;
>
>         AuthService.login(obj).then(function (data)
>         {
>             console.log(data);
>             $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
>
>             //$scope.setCurrentUser = function (data)
>             //{
>             //    $rootScope.$emit("setUserRoles", data);
>             //}
>              $scope.setCurrentUser(data);
>             $location.path('/addBank');
>             $scope.loading = false;
>         }, function (error) {
>             $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
>             alert("Bad");
>             $scope.loading = false;
>         });
>     }
> }]);
> ```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't the issue that you've commented out the definition of `$scope.setCurrentUser`? You can't call it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: This function is implement in another controller call
ApplicationController

but is this way access it in another Controller

Comment: Is your other controller loaded before this one? If you try to call the function before it's defined I would think you would get this.

Comment: Try posting your ApplicationController code so we can see what is being done there.

Comment: Thanks I figure it out